# How can I label points on a mapview map in r

Tags: r, r-mapview

Please help me label points on a mapview map.  I can plot the points ok.  I'd like to then label the points "Point A", "Point B".  I'd also prefer to do this without markers for the points i.e. I'll just use the coordinates to locate the labels.

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)
library(tidyverse)

points <- tribble(~name, ~lat, ~lon,
                     'Point A',     -38.119151, 145.401893,
                     'Point B',     -38.127870, 145.685598)

points_sf <- st_as_sf(points, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

mapview(points_sf)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is supported by `leaflet`, for which `mapview` depends on - but mapview adds other behavior on-top.

Here is the closest equivalent in `mapview` and how to do it exactly as requested in base `leaflet`.

**Note:** `mapview::addStaticLabels` is a wrapper for `leaflet::addLabelOnlyMarkers`.

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

points <- tribble(~name, ~lat, ~lon,
                  'Point A',     -38.119151, 145.401893,
                  'Point B',     -38.127870, 145.685598)

points_sf <- st_as_sf(points, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

leaflet(points_sf) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(label =  ~name, 
                      labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T,
                                                  direction = 'top',
                                                  textOnly = T))
```

### [image]

```
mapview(points_sf) %>%
  addStaticLabels(label = points$name,
                  noHide = TRUE,
                  direction = 'top',
                  textOnly = TRUE,
                  textsize = "20px")
```

[image]

Comment: map view doesn't seem to have the addStaticLabels. Error: 'addStaticLabels' is not an exported object from 'namespace:mapview'

Comment: @M.Beausoleil it was moved to the `{leafem}` package.
https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/blob/2fbb31e13a8bbe1c947b246fd4df5aa4ede35f57/R/extensions.R